# Creating a new root directory in an Eclipse project under version control

Tags: java, eclipse, git, ant

I'm working on a group project for my software engineering course, and my professor has indicated that I set up the directory structure incorrectly on Github. I'd like to correct the issue now to avoid a grade penalty, but I'm very new to using Git. Basically we have a structure that is as follows on Github.

```
src
--main
----java
------Source Files
--test
-----java
------Test Files
Various Ivy/Ant build files
.classpath
.gitignore
.git
.project
README.md
```

I need to create a new directory called CodeComp that will contain the directory structure above except for the README.md, which should be on the same level as the CodeComp directory.

Since our grade is dependent on the commit history, this would need to be preserved. Is there an easy way to do this or are we better off just taking the small deduction on the final project grade?

UPDATE:
In case anyone else has to do this in the future:

1. Go to the folder holding the project and create the new directory.
2. Move all files needed into the new directory except .* files. Refresh Eclipse.
3. Commit and Push the directory changes to the repo regardless of Eclipse errors.
4. Manually delete the .classpath, .gitignore, and .project files from the repository.
5. Back-up your .classpath and .gitignore files. Delete your local copy of the repo and re-clone it.
6. Import the Git project and choose to put the project files in your newly created directory.
7. Copy the .classpath and .gitignore you backed up into the new project directory. Push the changes.

Comment: Well as for your commit history, github's commit history is real easy to edit. You can even fake out the time of upload. But hey, I wonder if it counts under Academic Dishonesty :p

Comment: actually, your current structure looks better than the proposed one. It's more standard to have the current approach. Except for the target directory, that should never be in Git.

Comment: It's only to show how much each student contributed to the project for the individual portion of the grade. I've currently done like 80% of the project, so I really don't want to lose the history. lol

Comment: @ErikPragt Oops. I meant that's the directory structure in Eclipse. We don't have the target/ directory on Github. I'll edit.

Comment: @James Ah, better. Well, like I said, I think your current approach is better, plus I cannot imagine taking a hit on your grade for refactoring your project structure. Otherwise: [Git Rewrite History](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History)

Comment: We have already been docked a few points for incorrect structure on the project progress review. He'll dock us again on the final project review in a few days. I think he feels that the new structure is cleaner because you have CodeComp and README.md as the first items that appear in the repo, and all of the source, project, and build files are contained within it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory you should be able to use a standard file browser to move everything but your .git and Readme file into your new sub-folder and then commit that.

The git history will still there but it may see it as two separate files, one that has been deleted and one that is just created. In my experience Git doesn't really like moving files.

In any case, you commit history will still be in the repository, it will just be 2 separate sections from when you moved the files.

But, hey... It may pay to show that move anyway. I know for sure that I was moving files all around when I first learnt about version control. It's all learning.

EDIT: You can test this by committing the change locally and checking the history before you push it upstream to Github.

Comment: I actually tried that last night when I was trying to figure this out. I got Eclipse to see the directory changes when I was committing, but moving the .project file broke the Eclipse project. I wonder if I could push the directory changes, delete the .project file on GitHub, delete my local clone, and re-clone it. I could then import it as a new Git project in Eclipse and create a new project file. That might not break it.

Comment: That should work, I have done that before. Im not sure why it broke the project file though, none of my .project files have any location related data in them. 

You could maybe just remove the project from your eclipse workspace and then re-import the project once your done moving things?